# Can't run pip from virtual environment, powershell, Windows 10

Tags: python, powershell, pip, python-venv

Second edit:  I haven't been able to get "-m venv" or "virtualenv" working under powershell.  I found this:

```
https://github.com/regisf/virtualenvwrapper-powershell
```

and after installing it, it worked for a couple weeks.  After a windows update, the symptoms came back.  My workaround for now:

```
c:\ new-virtualenvwrapper  booklook
```

It gives and error message but you can activate the venv

Inside venv:

```
 PS C:\py\venvs\booklook> env:PYTHONPATH = "C:\py\venvs\booklook\Lib\site-packages\"

 > python -m ensurepip
 > python -m pip install pip
```

Using a text editor edit pip.exe (in virtual env Scripts directory)

You'll see toward bottom: c:\py\venvs\booklook\scripts\python.exe

Change the "scripts" to Scripts

Now pip works....

I suspect my problems started from some feature called "Windows aliases" that is supposed to make it more convenient for windows uses to find python.  If you're having trouble with python, type "aliases" in the start box and look for "Manage WIndows Execution Aliases", turn off python aliases.

---

Edited to show sys.path after activating venv.

"pip" works as expected from powershell cli when not using a virtual environment.  When the virtual environment starts I get `Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\py\venvs\x1\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts\pip.exe"'`

There are various reports of similar problems. I've reinstalled pip in the virtual environment, and I've used both `python -m venv` and virtualenv. Below are errors I am getting when using `-m venv`.

Edit: I think this is an important clue:  First to show python not in my regular path:

```
 PS C:\Users\pa2> python
 python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, funct
 ....
```

Then, once I activate venv, no useful-looking path -- in particular "venvs\x1\Scripts" is not there.  However, as shown in original post, even when I specifically call the pip that is generated by "-m venv", that pip errors out

```
 PS C:\Users\pa2> C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts\Activate.ps1
 (x1) PS C:\Users\pa2> python
 Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import sys
 >>> sys.path
 ['', 'C:\\py\\venvs\\x1\\Scripts\\python36.zip', 'C:\\users\\pa2\\appdata\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\users\\pa2\\appdata\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\users\\pa2\\appdata\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36', 'C:\\py\\venvs\\x1']
```

My question is how do I make it work so that pip runs and installs packages just in the virtual env?

Part of the issue is case-sensitivity, not shown here, I've tried creating a symlink of "scripts" pointing to "Scripts", when I do that, I get the "no module named pip" message.

In the final line, when it fails, the diagnostic is talking about pip in the system level (my appdata folder) instead of the virtual env.

This happens with both 3.6.6 and 3.8.1 on my home machine.  It doesn't happen on my work machine.

```
PS C:\> C:\users\pa2\appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe -m venv /py/venvs/x1
PS C:\> C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts\Activate.ps1
(x1) PS C:\> pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\py\venvs\x1\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts\pip.exe" '
(x1) PS C:\> cd C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts\
(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> python -m pip install rope
C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-45.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (584 kB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel
Successfully installed pip setuptools wheel
(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> ls -l pip.exe


    Directory: C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2/9/2020   7:02 PM         106344 pip.exe


(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> date

Sunday, February 9, 2020 7:02:25 PM


(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> python -m pip
C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts\python.exe: No module named pip
(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> pip
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\py\venvs\x1\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.

(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> cat env:path
C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin;C:\opt\spark\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin;c:\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\bin\;C:\Users\pa2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
(x1) PS C:\py\venvs\x1\Scripts> .\python.exe .\pip.exe install rope
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\pa2\appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\users\pa2\appdata\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File ".\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the enabled "case sensitive" attribute on the root directory for the virtual/venv environment is problematic under Windows. Disabling it allows `pip` to run correctly under `venv`.

To test:

1. `python -m venv myapp-venv`
2. `fsutil file setCaseSensitiveInfo myapp-venv disable`
3. `.\myapp-venv\Scripts\activate`
4. `pip --version`

Version information should display instead of an error message that looks something like this:

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\foo\myapp-venv\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Foo\myapp-venv\Scripts\pip.exe" --version': The system cannot find the file specified.